# Android gradle build Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to read manifest

Tags: android

I could build or run my app on IDEA/Android Studio.
But I can build it successfully on the same git branch using Jenkins.
So I do not know what is going on.

Here is the outputs I got:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to read manifest /Users/gongzelong/.android/build-cache/7a6a7706f3cec8ecf866a73dc32ecd4f769d6c2a/output/AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:201)

./gradlew clean :app:assembleDebug --info > ~/Desktop/build_info.txt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/gongzelong/.android/build-cache/7a6a7706f3cec8ecf866a73dc32ecd4f769d6c2a/output/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

I have tried the following ways but none work.

Rebuild
Invalidate and Restart 
Restart the Mac
./gradlew clean :category:assembleDebug可以
./gradlew clean :app:assembleDebug
Delete /Users/gongzelong/.android/build-cache/

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio every time builds the project, it will unpack the aar file to  your /Users/gongzelong/.android/build-cache/ folder. I met this issue before, and it was because the aar file I built have issue, it's missing AndroidManifest.xml file inside. So try to check the folder content inside 7a6a7706f3cec8ecf866a73dc32ecd4f769d6c2a/output to know which aar file have issue, and try to check if the aar file inside the project or built by your project is completed or not.

Your local machine may have that AndroidManifest.xml in your build-cache before, but your Jenkins machine don't have. That's why it's not working on your Jenkins machine.